# Python return specific alphabet if match in specific range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below logic.

```
0-9 (Return number 0,1,2,3,...9)
10-14 (Return A)
15-19 (Return B)
20-24 (Return C)
.... And so on till Z.

# 4 interval for the next alphabet
```

my code

```
def char_finder(number):

    if number in range(0, 9+1):
        return number
    if number in range(10, 14+1):
        return 'A'
    if number in range(15, 19+1):
        return 'B'
    # ....
    # so on till z
    if number in range(134, 138+1):
        return 'Z'
    return 'Z'
```

I need a better solution.

Comment: Have a look at `chr()`

Comment: Can you think of a *mathematical rule* that tells you which case the `number` matches? For example, try to think of a rule that turns values `in range(10, 14+1) into `0`, values `in range(15, 19+1)` into `1`, etc. Hint: use integer division. Next, can you think of a way to convert that value into the desired letter? (Hint: what if you had a list, or a string, that contains all those letters in order? Or perhaps you've heard of a builtin function called `chr` that might be useful here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic works out to:

- if a (positive) number is less than 10, return it as a character;
- otherwise, subtract 10, divide by 5 and use the result as an index into the alphabet and return that letter.

Apparently, you don't expect values over 139.

So:

```
def char_finder(number):
    assert 0 <= number <= 139
    if number < 10:
        return str(number)
    else:
        # chr(65) is 'A'
        return chr(65 + (number - 10) // 5)
```

If you're wondering why `chr()` magically matches 65 to `'A'`, that's because it returns the character that has the matching ASCII value for values this low. ASCII is a set of 128 characters that includes the entire alphabet in uppercase, starting at 65, as well as the entire alphabet in lowercase, starting at 97.

ASCII is included in the UTF character set, with the same indices and that's what the `chr()` function does, it returns the character with that index in the UTF character set.